# How to check if there is NOT a class in an array of elements transformed from a NodeList

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title suggests, I am trying to check if a class doesn't exist in an array.

When clicking, IF the button with #CNC_Mach_btn contains an .active class then the anchor tags with .CNC_Machinery class in it should receive a .show class, this part works.

However, I also want to remove the .show class on anchor tags without a .CNC_Machinery class.

I changed the NodeLists to arrays and then iterate through them and then appended .show

I tried the JS idea, just adding an '!', (!CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) from [here](https://techstacker.com/posts/cXTuMZ2XutfH36SYc/vanilla-javascript-how-to-check-if-a-class-exists-practical)
but that didn't work.

JS:

```
      let category_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.category-button');
      let CNC_Mach_btn = document.getElementById("CNC_Machining_button");

      let Images_Class_In_Anchor_Tag = document.querySelectorAll('.images');

      const All_Images_Class_MakeArray = Array.from(Images_Class_In_Anchor_Tag);
      //gets .CNC_Machinery classes from anchor tags where also .images class is located
      let CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag = document.querySelectorAll(".CNC_Machinery");

      const CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray = Array.from(CNC_Machining_Class_In_AnchorTag);



    CNC_Mach_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

       if (CNC_Mach_btn.classList.contains("active")) {
        CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.add("show"));  
        if (!All_Images_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.contains("CNC_Machinery"))) {
        CNC_Machining_Class_MakeArray.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show"));
        }
      }
    });
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<div id="category-buttons">
    <h5>Choose image category</h5>
      <button id="All" class="category-button active" >All Categories</button>
      <button id="CNC_Machining_button" class="category-button CNC_Mach_btn">CNC_Machining</button>
      <button id="HP_Die_Casting_button" class="category-button HP_Die_btn">HP Die Casting</button>
      <button id="Iron_Casting" class="category-button">Iron Casting</button>
      <button id="Steel_Casting" class="category-button">Steel Casting</button>
      <button id="Precision_Casting" class="category-button">Precision Casting</button>
      <button id="Aluminium_Casting" class="category-button">Aluminum Casting</button>
    </div>


<section class="gallery-links">
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2 class="product-gallery-title">Product Gallery</h2>

  <div class="gallery-container">
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery DESC';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
      echo 'SQL statement failed!';
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //what's echoed out by the database

        echo '  <a class="images '.$row["image_category"].'" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].')">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                </div>
                </a>';
      }
    }


    ?>  

  </div>

</div>
```

THE PHP OUTPPUT IN DEVTOOLS of the anchor tags including the CNC_Machinery class.

```
                <a class="images CNC_Machinery show" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/galvanized_cast_iron.UNIQid5c3720c4502f92.46784406.jpg)">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>Galvanized_Cast_Iron</h3>
                <p>Image of connector manufactured in Galvanized_Cast_Iron_Way</p>
                </div>
                </a>  <a class="images Sand_Casting" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image: url(gallery/pizza-pie.UNIQid5c372f19564787.51280655.jpg)">
                <div class="color-overlay">
                <h3>Cool pic</h3>
                <p>When workers work</p>
                </div>
                </a>
```

Expected Result: .show should be added to anchor tag which contains .CNC_Machinery
.show is NOT added and Removed from the anchor tags which DO NOT contain .CNC_Machinery

Actual Result: no output from JS.

Comment: You can use array.some() to check if one element in the array contains that class. Keep in mind that you can also use querySelectorAll() on elements, not only on document. So something like `parentElement.querySelectorAll( 'a:not(.CNC_Machinery)');` will give you the nodelist of all the hyperlinks without the CNC_Machinery class. Same way can you select `parentElement.querySelectorAll( 'a.active.CNC_Machinery)');` to get all the links that have both classes so you can remove them again.

Comment: I am exploring this. Interestingly the method with querySelectorAll( 'a:not(.CNC_Machinery)') is not even described in MDN.

Comment: You can use any CSS selector inside querySelector() . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors  So with a bit of creativity, you can select the exact nodes you want from the start and only have to loop to change them.